# Android Attempt to read from field on a null object reference

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` with some `Fragments` used in a `ViewPager`, sometimes user sends me some crash report that i don't understand.

I can not produce this crash and most of the user have no problem at all.

The crash Log says:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.mehdok.views.treeview.TreeNode$TreeNodeClickListener com.mehdok.mafatih.MainActivity.nodeClickListener2' on a null object reference
```

The `nodeClickListener2` is in my main activity:

```
public TreeNode.TreeNodeClickListener nodeClickListener2 = new TreeNode.TreeNodeClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(TreeNode node, Object value)
    {
        TreeViewHolderNoBorder.TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewHolderNoBorder.TreeViewItem) value;
        if(node.isLeaf() && !item.nodeNavUri.equals(""))
        {
            openNodePage2(item);
        }
    }
};
```

And in fragmets i use it like this:

```
tView.setDefaultNodeClickListener(((MainActivity) getActivity()).nodeClickListener2);
```

What can i do to prevent this crash?

tnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you access your activity field from your fragment? You should do it starting from onAttach() up until onDetach().

If you try to access it too soon like in your constructor or in your fragment's onCreate(), this would explain the crash. Same if you try to access it after the fragment is detached from the Activity.

Comment: In my Main Activity I have a method for time Calculation, when it's done it call a function (`fillViews`) from fragment to fill its view based of this date. In `fillViews` i will check for null views (in case date calculation done faster that fragment `onCreateView` called).

Comment: An Activity should never call a method directly on a Fragment. The fragment should pull the information it needs at the right time.

Comment: This saved my life, all i had to do was move my method to onActivityCreated

Answer (score 0):

That is possible, sometimes Activity will be recycled, when you call `getActivity()` in Fragment, it will return null. so before you call `getActivity()` you can write code as below:

```
if (isAdded()) {
        tView.setDefaultNodeClickListener(((MainActivity) getActivity()).nodeClickListener2);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I thought `Fragment` lifeCycle depends on hosting Activity. is that wrong?

Comment: @mehdok Fragment is actually a view.

Comment: what if i make `nodeClickListener2` static? might this problem happens again?

Comment: @mehdok the problem will happen again, do what I wrote in my answer

Comment: this prevent the crash, but if `if` statement goes `false` then the app wont work correctly.

Comment: @mehdok don't worry about that, when your Activity is recreate, the code will be executed again, it will work correctly